# What are default credentials for docker cloud Ubuntu node?

Tags: docker, couchdb, digital-ocean, docker-cloud

I created a Ubuntu 14.04.5 x64 node on Digital Ocean via Docker cloud and deployed couchdb service on this node successfully. However, the service is not available with http://:5984/_utils/config.html url. I wanted to connect to Ubuntu  node via putty to verify couch db deployment; But I am not aware of default credentials for docker cloud Ubuntu node?

Comment: Ubuntu Server usually has a default user named 'ubuntu' often with password 'ubuntu'. I've also seen ubuntu Docker images that use 'root/root'.